# Entered value in the input box matches any of the values in the array

Tags: javascript

```
function start() {
    var arrNums = [18,23,20,17,21,18,22,19,18,20];
    var searchValue, index, result;
    searchValue = Number(document.getElementById("searchValue").value);
    index = 0;
    result = " ";
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+="The values in the array are: ";
    while(index < arrNums.length) {

        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= arrNums[index] + " ";
        index++;
    }

    index = 0;

    while (index < arrNums.length) {
        if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The number" + result + " exists in the array";
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The values in this example do match the vaules you must use.";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The number" + result + " does not exist in the array";
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The values in this example do not match the vaules you must use.";
        }
        index++;
    }
}


function clearOutput() {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" ";
}
```

When I run the code I can get the "The values in the array are:" with all numbers to print out then the next part repeats the "else" about 10 times. How do I fix this, Thank you

Comment: It's only a matter of time till `innerHTML += ` will get you in trouble. Better use `appendChild(someNode)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function start() {
    var arrNums = [18,23,20,17,21,18,22,19,18,20];
    var searchValue, index, result, found; // found flag
    var text = ""; // for test reasons I will use text field instead of yours HTML element.
    found = false; // false at beginning
    searchValue = 20; // test value
    index = 0;
    //searchValue = 0; why would you constantly search for 0?
    text += "The values in the array are: ";
    while(index < arrNums.length) {
        text += arrNums[index] + " ";
        index++;
    }

    index = 0 // reset pointer

    while (index < arrNums.length) {
        if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
            text += "The number " + searchValue + " exists in the array";
            text += "The values in this example do match the vaules you must use.";
            found = true; // true if found
            break; // if found break from while
        }
        
        index++;
    }

    if (!found) { // if not found
       text += "The number " + searchValue + " does not exist in the array";
       text += "The values in this example do not match the vaules you must use.";
    }
    
    console.log(text);
}

start();
```

Comment: Only the 'if (!found)' is working, so every number I try search for is saying it isn't found

Comment: Did you got rid of searchValue = 0. Plese post your current code in pastebin abd show me

Comment: I have copied the code you gave me exactly how it is but i still have the 'function clearOutput() {
 document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=" ";
}' part in my code

Comment: I have created a fiddle so you can see that it works. Something wrong with your other code or HTML.

Comment: yeah it works but you put 'searchValue = 20' so now you are constantly searching for 20, if i take that line out then the code dosnt work, i get "The number undefined does not exist in the array"

Comment: Yep sorry, i just went through my html again and noticed a mistake my bad, thanks for the help

Comment: I do not understand how this could possibly be the "best answer" when you have an answer below (updated many times following additional information in the question) which contains multiple approaches to your issue (along with working examples) and, most importantly, an __explanation__ of what the code is doing aswell.

Answer (score 1):

The second `while` does nothing because the variable `index` has been incremented after each iteration of the first `while` loop. You need to reset your `index` counter prior to the second `while` like so.

```
while(index < arrNums.length) {

    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= arrNums[index] + " ";
    index++;
}

index = 0;

while (index < arrNums.length) {
    if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The number" + result + " exists in the array";
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The values in this example do match the vaules you must use.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The number" + result + " does not exist in the array";
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The values in this example do not match the vaules you must use.";
    }
    index++;
}
```

**UPDATE FOLLOWING QUESTION CHANGE**

'IF' jQuery is an option, you could utilise the [`inArray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function, which will return the index of the "found" element in the array or -1 if "not found".

For example, in place of your second `while` loop:

```
var isFoundAtPosition = jQuery.inArray(Number(searchValue), arrNums);
if(isFoundAtPosition > -1) {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+="The number " + searchValue + " exists in the array at position " + isFoundAtPosition;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+= "The number" + searchValue + " does not exist in the array";
}
```

And, if jQuery is not an option, you could achieve the same outcome with the following Javascript:

```
index = 0;
var numberFound = false;
while (index < arrNums.length) {
    if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
        numberFound = true;
        break;
    } 
    index++;
}
if(numberFound) {
   document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML+="The number " + searchValue + " exists in the array at position " + index;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Okay, I have made a few examples (one using Javascript and one using jQuery). Hopefully these will help:

**Javascript**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" onchange="valueChanged(this.value)" id="searchValue">
  <div id="msg"></div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  function valueChanged(searchValue) {
    var arrNums = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
    var index = 0;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "Values in the array are: ";
    while (index < arrNums.length) {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += arrNums[index] + " ";
      index++;
    }
    index = 0;
    var numberFound = false;
    while (index < arrNums.length) {
    console.log(searchValue, arrNums[index])
      if (arrNums[index] == searchValue) {
        alert("Number found");
        numberFound = true;
        break;
      }
      index++;
    }
    if (numberFound) {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "The number " + searchValue + " exists";
    }
  }
</script>
```

**jQuery**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" onchange="valueChanged(this.value)" id="searchValue">
  <div id="msg"></div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  function valueChanged(searchValue) {
    var arrNums = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
    var index = 0;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "Values in the array are: ";
    while (index < arrNums.length) {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += arrNums[index] + " ";
      index++;
    }
    var isFoundAtPosition = jQuery.inArray(Number(searchValue), arrNums);
    console.log(isFoundAtPosition);
    if (isFoundAtPosition > -1) {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "The number " + searchValue + " exists in the array at position " + isFoundAtPosition;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += "The number" + searchValue + " does not exist in the array";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The reason you are entering the `else` ten times is because this is the number of items in `arrNums` and, presumably, `searchValue` does not equal any element in `arrNums`. What do you wish to achieve from the above code? I.e. Do you just want to search `arrNums` for the `searchValue` and then exit the loop? Because there are much easier ways of achieving this (if jQuery is also an option)? And, if not, I can update my answer so that the search will stop after finding the `searchValue`.

Comment: Or is the problem that your `searchValue` does equal a value in `arrNums` and `arrNums[index] == searchValue` isn't working for you?

Comment: Yeah I want it so it runs through once and tells me either that it found the number or it didn't

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you an option using `jQuery` and `Javascript`

Comment: When you say doesn't work, are there any errors in your console window? Can you update the question to show the attempts you have made? Can you make up your own code snippet on Fiddler to demonstrate what "doesn't work"