# How to use a value to check a radio button in a function jquery

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

So I am trying to have my code where c is the value of B1 (i.e. 1), However it's not working.

When I replace c with a number in the switch statement it works, but everything I've tried, I can't get c to hold a the value of B1.

```js
// $("#B1").prop("checked", true); // this works

var c = $("#B1").val(); // this doesnt work
switch (c) {
  case 1:
    $("#B1").prop("checked", true);
    break;
  case 2:
    $("#B2").prop("checked", true);
    break;
  case 3:
    $("#B3").prop("checked", true);
    break;
  case 4:
    document.getElementById("B4").checked = true;
    break;
  case 5:
    document.getElementById("B5").checked = true;
    break;
  case 6:
    document.getElementById("B6").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<title>jquery set radio button checked based on value - itsolutionstuff.com</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id='B1' value="1"> Completely Dissimilar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B2" value="2"> Not Equivalent,but Same Topic&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B3" value="3"> Not Equivalent, But Shares Some Details&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B4" value="4"> Roughly Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B5" value="5"> Mostly Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B6" value="${Sscore1}"> Completely Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: 1 <> "1" - change the switch to test strings or change c to be int

Comment: The tag info of [radio] starts with "the transmission of signals through free space by electromagnetic radiation". Please read those as you are typing in the tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entered value in the input box matches any of the values in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979197/entered-value-in-the-input-box-matches-any-of-the-values-in-the-array) or [Using Javascript to compare two input numbers in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15914514/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey There is nothing in the first link you post that can even hint to OP what is worng

Comment: @mplungjan Well, luckily you have a gold badge and can mark the correct duplicate...

Comment: I did. Thanks ....

Answer (score 1):

1 is not equal to "1"

Change the switch to test strings or change the c to be integer like this

```
var c = +$("#B1").val(); // this now works too
```

```js
var c = +$("#B1").val(); // this now works too
switch (c) {
  case 1:
    $("#B1").prop("checked", true);
    break;
  case 2:
    $("#B2").prop("checked", true);
    break;
  case 3:
    $("#B3").prop("checked", true);
    break;
  case 4:
    $("#B4").prop("checked", true);
    break;
  case 5:
    $("#B5").prop("checked", true);
    break;
  case 6:
    $("#B6").prop("checked", true);
}
```

```html
<title>jquery set radio button checked based on value - itsolutionstuff.com</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id='B1' value="1"> Completely Dissimilar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B2" value="2"> Not Equivalent,but Same Topic&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B3" value="3"> Not Equivalent, But Shares Some Details&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B4" value="4"> Roughly Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B5" value="5"> Mostly Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B6" value="${Sscore1}"> Completely Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Or just do this

```
var c = $("#B1").val(); // this now works too
$("#B"+c).prop("checked", true);
```

```js
var c = $("#B1").val(); // this now works too
$("#B"+c).prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<title>jquery set radio button checked based on value - itsolutionstuff.com</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id='B1' value="1"> Completely Dissimilar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B2" value="2"> Not Equivalent,but Same Topic&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B3" value="3"> Not Equivalent, But Shares Some Details&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B4" value="4"> Roughly Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B5" value="5"> Mostly Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="Semantic score1" id="B6" value="${Sscore1}"> Completely Equivalent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try transforming c into a number.

```
var c = parseInt( $( "#B1" ).val());
```

Comment: @mplungjan As was already answered in multiple duplicates... :P